# Where can I find a Sphinx charset_table that is suitable for "almost all" languages?

Tags: sphinx, character-encoding

I'm looking for a Sphinx `charset_table` that is suitable for natural language "almost all" languages.

I understand that "almost all" is quite a vague definition. So the requirement can be restated in such a way that the `charset_table` must be suitable to at least the following language codes:

```
de, en, fr, nl, sv, fi, pl, cs, da, no, sl, pt, el, sk, it
```

Given those requirements what would be a suitable `charset_table`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one of MySQL's collations, for example [utf8_general_ci](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_general_ci.european.html), would be suitable (even if you don't use MySQL) or would be a decent starting point that you can adapt then you might find this useful: http://thefsb.wordpress.com/2010/12/